# Passing parameters id in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like select my params id in my controller and I want how i can do this.

So for exemple I have :

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

But I want select only the article one. 
So how i can write that ?

I think that was that :

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id => '1'])
```

EDIT
 I have the solution (thank's to : oldergod and Ryan Bigg ) =>

```
Article.find(1)
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? `params[:id]` always contains one and only one id

Comment: What about `Article.find(1)`

Comment: Yeah thank's @oldergod , that was I search :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find only the article with ID=1:

```
Article.find(1)
```

For more information like this, please read the [Active Record Querying Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@article = Article.first()
```

for first article record.

Comment: `.find(1)` and `.first` don't necessarily give the same result.